# My app won't connect to server after published in play store

Tags: android, apk

I just published my app to play store and have a huge issue: APK published by google's store won't connect to my server. If I install the same .apk in my phone it works fine, but after googles processing the .apk and put it on play store it stops working. Have no idea even how to start to debug this. Any help or advice?

Comment: Please add more details about your app. I.e the data source it is trying to connect, etc.

Comment: play store generates its own signing certificates when you publish your app through play store I think you need to check in your console for the the play store signing certificates and use them to authenticate your requests

Comment: Just using FCM...

Comment: Could "minifyEnabled" and "shrinkResources" cause this? never used it before...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to check the permissions for your app. If you tested it on your phone it is possible that you took for granted that it could connect to the internet because you wanted it to. 
So I would check again the manifest file to make sure you added that permission for the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You can find something useful here : [Android connect to the network](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting)

As a second step in a debug process I would check my code for the connection to the server. What are you using as a backend? Firebase?
If you want to share more, I'll try to help.

**Update**
The problem was solved by disabling "minifyEnabled" and "shrinkResources".

Comment: Sorry, I was so frustrated I forgot to put more details: 

my manifest: 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 

If I install the .apk manually in my phone it works fine. If I install the version from Play store it does not work

Comment: So your manifest looks ok. You said you're using Firebase Cloud Messaging right? I doubt it has something to do with it but you should give it a try at disabling "minifyEnabled" and "shrinkResources". This should only cause problems with resources, not with the connection, but at least you can rule that out.

Comment: You should try to build without those options because sometimes they cause crashes and (consider that I'm not looking at your code) if something goes wrong maybe it also prevents your app to successfully connect to the internet. Other things to check that come to mind are: are you installing on your phone a **release** version of the app or a **debug** one? I ask because sometimes they behave in different ways.

Comment: You nailed it! Disabling "minifyEnabled" and "shrinkResources" it works fine again. Thanks

Comment: I'm happy for you! Could you please accept the answer than so that everyone knows it worked for you?